# Converting excel files to python to frequency

Tags: python, excel, time, fft, frequency

Essentially I've got an excel files with voltage in the first column, and time in the second. I want to find the period of the voltages, as it returns a graph of voltage in y axis and time in x axis with a periodicity, looking similar to a sine function.

To find the frequency I have uploaded my excel file to python as I think this will make it easier- there may be something I've missed that will simplify this.

So far in python I have:

```
import xlrd
import numpy as N
import numpy.fft as F
import matplotlib.pyplot as P

wb = xlrd.open_workbook('temp7.xls') #LOADING EXCEL FILE
wb.sheet_names()
sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

first_column = sh.col_values(1) #VALUES FROM EXCEL
second_column = sh.col_values(2) #VALUES FROM EXCEL
```

Now how do I find the frequency from this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how much you know about the Fourier transform, so forgive me if this is too much background.
Your signal does not have "a frequency", it is but it can be thought of as the sum of many frequencies. The Fourier transform will tell you the weights of all the frequencies that make up your signal. Unfortunately information may be lost when sampling from the analog (continuous time) to digital (discrete time) domain. This puts a constraint on the information we can get about frequency - namely that the maximum frequency component we can determine is related to the digital sampling rate ([Nyquist-Shannon criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem)):

```
fs > 2B
```

Where `fs` is your sampling rate (samples/unit time, typically in Hz or something like it), and `B` is the maximum frequency of your signal. If your signal *actually* has frequencies higher than `B` they will be "aliased" to some value lower than `B`.

For your problem, all you have to do is this:

```
x = N.array(first_column)
X = F.fft(x)
```

Now `X` is the frequency-domain representation of your voltage signal. The corresponding frequency axis covers `[0, fs)`, based on the sampling theorem. So, what is `fs`? You need to calculate that by looking at the number of samples you have divided by the total duration of your sampled signal (note your units here):

```
fs = len(second_column) / second_column[-1]
```

Note that this representation of your signal will also (probably) be complex, i.e. each frequency will have an associated amplitude and phase.

Hopefully this helps, and hopefully I didn't cover a bunch of stuff you already knew.

Comment: The OP has two columns, time and voltage.  You cannot assume all time steps are the same, so you'll first have to interpolate the signal to a unifomrly sampled signal (using `numpy.interp1d()` or similar) to be able to perform a meaningful FFT.

Comment: Fair enough. Suffice to say there is added complexity if you are dealing with a non-uniformly sampled signal.

Comment: My code now returns a sampling rate fs (the rate of recordings??), and X gives a complex number, do I need to absolute this value?

Comment: As in absolute it if I want to plot frequency on the x axis?

Comment: It depends on what information you want. Plotting the absolute value of `X` will give you the *amplitude* of the frequency components. This is probably what you want, but you could also plot the *phase* (angle) which may be important in some applications. Phase terms are also important if you want to reconstruct your original signal.